# How to use DbContext with DI in desktop applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-core, dependency-injection

I've been working on several non-web applications with `Entity Framework` and always it was struggling for me to find a correct approach for implementing `Generic Repository` with DbContext.

I've searched a lot, many of articles are about web applications which have short-living contexts. In desktop approaches I can't find suitable method.

One approach is `DbContext per ViewModel` but I don't agree with coupling View with Repository layers.

Another one is using `using` clause this way:

```
using(var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    // ...
}
```

but this way we will not have `Unit of Work` and also can't use `IoC Containers`.

So what is the best practice for using DbContext in desktop applications?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a real problem here.  The ViewModel _is_ the Unit of Work abstraction for desktop apps.  And so if you don't want a transient DbContext, scope it to the ViewModel.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have two problem here to use DbContext directly. First I don't think it's good idea to couple ViewModel in UI layer to DbContext in Model layer directly it makes problems if someday I want change my EF to for example Dapper. Second forms like `Main Form` is long-running and I don't think it's good idea to keep some DbContexts of forms ViewModels alive until termination of application. As I know it's advised to keep DbContext lifetime as short as possible.

Comment: ViewModel is _not_ in the UI layer.  That's the View.  And for long-lived ViewModels, like the one supporting the main form, don't have database access, or use only transient DBContext instances.  And whether you use the DbContext directly or wrap it in an additional repository layer is an unrelated concern, with its own set of tradeoffs.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I got your point. You said in terms of DbContext usage, we can see ViewModels something like Controllers in web apps (if I got it correctly!)

Comment: Yes.  Kind of like controllers.  Typically longer-lived as a typical ViewModel handles Load,Display,Edit,Save end-to-end.  But in terms of DbContext usage, similar.

Comment: DBContext should be instantiated, used and disposed rather than retained. Either that is directly in (say) a command of the viewmodel or  in a method of a wrapper class which itself should be instantiated, used and disposed. Make viewmodels self tracking ( for changes ) and copy data from the vm to dto/EF models and vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `DbContext` is meant to be short-lived: it represents a unit-of-work in itself. If you need long-term object state management then you can use the `ObjectStateManager` in Entity Framework directly.

For ensuring access to a `DbContext`, add an interface `IDbContextFactory<TDbContext>` (or just `IMyDbContextFactory` if you only have a single `DbContext` type) and inject that into your ViewModels and use a short-lived `DbContext` from it:

```
interface IDbContextFactory<TDbContext>
    where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    TDbContext Create();
}

// Configure:

void ConfigureServices( YourContainer container )
{
    container.RegisterSingleton( IDbContextFactory<YourDbContextType1>, // etc );
    container.RegisterSingleton( IDbContextFactory<YourDbContextType2>, // etc );
    container.RegisterSingleton( IDbContextFactory<YourDbContextType3>, // etc );
}

// Usage:

public class LongLivedViewModel
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<YourDbContextType3> dbFactory;

    public LongLivedViewModel( IDbContextFactory<YourDbContextType3> dbFactory)
    {
        this.dbFactory = dbFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbFactory));

        this.DoSomethingCommand = new RelayCommand( this.DoSomethingAsync )
    }

    public RelayCommand DoSomethingCommand { get; }

    public async RelayCommand DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        using( YourDbContextType3 db = this.dbFactory.Create() )
        {
            // do stuff

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Entity Framework Core has a built in IDbContextFactory interface.

If using SQL Server, for instance, you declare the following in the ConfigureServices method (which in WPF is generally put in App.xaml.cs).

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(
        options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(MyConnectionString));
}
```

Make sure MyDbContext exposes this constructor:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

After that use constructor injection in the class that will be using the context (which could be either in the ViewModel layer or the Model layer, depending on your architecture):

```
private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _contextFactory;

public ModelClass(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> contextFactory)
{
    this._contextFactory = contextFactory;
}

public void DatabaseOperationMethod()
{
    using (var context = this._contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        // Do database stuff
    }
}
```