# DbContextFactory in WPF .Net 6 project (EF, MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-core, mvvm

My application is working fine when I use a plain/classic `DBContext` implementation, but when I try `DbContextFactory`, `_contextFactory.CreateDbContext()` is always failing with 'null' exception. What am I missing?

My `App.xaml.cs` (no changes were needed in this file whilst using `DBContext`):

```
private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string defaultConnection = Settings.Default.DefaultConnection;

    services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(defaultConnection, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(defaultConnection)));

    services.AddTransient(typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

`MyDbContext.cs` file (no changes were needed as it seems to match `DbContextFactory` constructor's requirements already):

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    // DbSets 

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            string defaultConnection = Settings.Default.DefaultConnection;

            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                            .UseMySql(defaultConnection, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(defaultConnection))
                            .Options;
        }

        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        // To be disabled in production 
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Table building logic for EF code-first
    }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs` file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _contextFactory;

    private SomeVieModel _someVieModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var _context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext(); // Throws 'null' exception

        // Probably should be instantiating a new DbContext 
        // in the VM itself, instead of passing it on? 
        _someVieModel = new SomeVieModel(_context); 
    }
}
```

I've checked numerous Blazor examples, because of the lack of WPF ones, and I feel I'm missing something very simple, some one line of `DbContextFactory` object instantiation? Like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66342915/1380473) - where is `IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> contextFactory` object coming from and where is it instantiated? Thank you!

Comment: The error was, that you didn't inject `IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>` into the `MainWindow` constructor. That's why the factory never got instantiated and you got the `NullReferenceException`. Everything else looks fine - maybe except for injecting something into the window which then just passes it on to the viewmodel instead of injecting things where they are needed. But that is about design and not about the error you got.

Comment: Thank you, Jürgen! It makes sense what you are saying, and I was partially considering it, but somehow in my mind it looked like a bad idea to be amending the very main window in such a way. Of course, it's just like any other window and I should just have done it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've worked it out, although I'm sure some of you will be pointing out the error of my ways :)

I just realised, that I've already had my own `DbContextFactory` class created for database migrations, because otherwise the EF Core could not connect to the database via project's `DbContext` class alone.

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[]? args = null)
    {
        string defaultConnection = Settings.Default.DefaultConnection;

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(defaultConnection, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(defaultConnection));

        return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

I've commented the code in `App.xaml.cs` out and initialised `DbContextFactory` via my own class instead of `IDbContextFactory` interface:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MyDbContextFactory  _contextFactory;

    private SomeVieModel _someVieModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _contextFactory = new MyDbContextFactory();

        _someVieModel = new SomeVieModel(_contextFactory); 
    }
}
```

And called `CreateDbContext()` in a view model:

```
public class SomeVieModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly MyDbContextFactory _contextFactory;

    public SomeVieModel(MyDbContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory; 
        
        await LoadDBStuff();
    }
    
    private async Task LoadDBStuff()
    {
        using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            await context.SomeDataModel.LoadAsync();
            SomeDataModelObservableCollection = context.SomeDataModel.Local.ToObservableCollection();
        }
    }
}
```